# For loop prints only last value array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (var i = 0; i < featureSet.features.length; i++) {
                 for (var f = 0, f1 = featureTracts.length; f < f1; f++) {

                     rows["Sensor"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Sensor;
                     rows["Resolution"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Resolution;
                     rows["Dtofparse"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Dtofparse;//PATH_ROW
                     // alert(rows);
                 }

                 resosat1[i] = rows;

             }
```

i am trying to print all values in  resosat1[i] array but it will take only last value and all values overwirite and update only last value to array

Comment: Well, you don’t create a new `rows` object each time. You’re using the same `rows` in each iteration of the loop.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: Please provide with dummy data for featureSet and featureTracts and also provide with the desired output based on the dummy data that you provide.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < featureSet.features.length; i++) {
             var rowAaaray = [];
             for (var f = 0, f1 = featureTracts.length; f < f1; f++) {
                 var rows = {};
                 rows["Sensor"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Sensor;
                 rows["Resolution"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Resolution;
                 rows["Dtofparse"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Dtofparse;//PATH_ROW
                 // alert(rows);
              rowAaaray.push(rows);
             }

             resosat1[i] = rowAaaray;

         }

 }
```

Because you are maintaining one variable and overriding it in loop. So you will get last overwritten object only.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the guy in the comment. Try:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < featureSet.features.length; i++) {
                 for (var f = 0, f1 = featureTracts.length; f < f1; f++) {

                     rows["Sensor"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Sensor;
                     rows["Resolution"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Resolution;
                     rows["Dtofparse"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Dtofparse;//PATH_ROW
                     resosat1[f] = rows; <======== THIS WILL STORE THE VALUE OF EACH ROW CREATED
                 }

                 <==//TRY STORING THE resosat1 array In another array here instead. 
                   //eg. arrayEx[i]=resosat1
                   //Alternatively, you could use a 2D Array eg. arrayEx[i][f]

             }
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

try this one..

```
      for (var i = 0; i < featureSet.features.length; i++) {
         var arr = []; // create array 
         for (var f = 0, f1 = featureTracts.length; f < f1; f++) {
             var rows = {};
             rows["Sensor"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Sensor;
             rows["Resolution"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Resolution;
             rows["Dtofparse"] = featureTracts[f].attributes.Dtofparse;//PATH_ROW
             // alert(rows);
          arr.push(rows);
         }

         resosat1[i] = arr;

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

*rows* is undeclared (at least in your snippet).

On the other hand, putting `var rows = {}`, as some suggest, will fix your problem because it creates new object each time. But, if your javascript version accepts it, it would be better to declare it wit *let* because, this way, you will be **really** creating new fresh variable (in block scope).

Declaring rows in an outer block will not fix your problem because you will be assigning same object during the whole loop.